# What is the most straight-forward method to deploy a new workflow definition in Alfresco Community 4.0.e?

Tags: workflow, alfresco

I am having a hard time deploying a new workflow definition in Alfresco Community 4.0.e. Alfresco does not have any user interface for this in the Community Edition. I could not find any Alfresco add-on related to this either. I have had a look at a lot of pages discussing this, such as these:

- [Difficulties in deploying my own workflow in alfresco workflow console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11601328/difficulties-in-deploying-my-own-workflow-in-alfresco-workflow-console)
- [Add new workflow into Alfresco share](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963360/add-new-workflow-into-alfresco-share)
- https://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/Custom_Share_Workflow_UI
- http://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/Workflow_Console
- http://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/Dynamic_Models#Dynamic_workflow_process_definitions
- http://www.jorambarrez.be/blog/2011/01/05/adhoc-workflow-with-activiti-kickstart/
- http://www.jorambarrez.be/blog/2012/11/28/from-design-to-execution-in-a-matter-of-minutes/
- http://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/Workflow_on_Share

However, I could not get it to work yet. As the BPMS is a key subsystem of Alfresco, I am nearly sure I not using the correct instructions.

What is the most straight-forward method to deploy a new workflow definition in Alfresco 4.0.e? Are there any clear step-by-step instructions, for dummies :) which I can follow?

Comment: What workflow engine are you targetting? Activiti or JBPM? (The answer will depend a lot on that)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you missed the most important wiki:
http://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/WorkflowAdministration

Here you can install the Eclipse plugin for JBPM.
Make sure you enable these properties:

```
### BPM Engine ###
system.workflow.engine.jbpm.enabled=true
system.workflow.engine.jbpm.definitions.visible=true
system.workflow.deployservlet.enabled=true
```

If you configure the plugin correctly, then automatic deployment of the workflow is possible. (Still need to restart when deploying models)

If you want to follow the activiti path then:
http://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/Workflow_with_Activiti

Almost the same path, like installing an Eclipse plugin or using another BPMN20 designer.
The only different aspect is that you need to manually deploy the workflow (export as .bar file and import it in the Activiti admin-console)

Comment: But the Activiti Admin Console is just in Enterprise edition. Is there any way to deploy Activiti workflow in the community edition?

Comment: activiti admin console is also in community version, maybe there is no link to it from within Share, but it should be. Then again you can always deploy workflows through the XML bean, only a restart is required.