# how to deploy workflow in alfresco community

Tags: workflow, alfresco, alfresco-share, activiti

I'm using the alfresco 4.2c community installed by a bin installer.

I've ready the workflow in another machine doing by maven sdk. I found that the folder structure is not the same as 4.2 community. For example, I got a file named "service-context.xml" for a workflow bean deployer while 4.2 community doesn't have this file.

I search from google that 4.2c community has a extension folder:

> tomcat/shared/classes/alfresco/extension

Should I create the folder structure under this folder? or I just simply place the 4 files: bean deployer, model, workflow.bpmn and share-config-custom.xml inside?

Also, there has a extension folder called "web-extension":

> tomcat/shared/classes/alfresco/web-extension

May I know this is use for place the share-config-custom.xml (Share Forms)?

A snippet of the service-context.xml:

```
<bean id="${project.artifactId}.workflowBootstrap" parent="workflowDeployer">
    <property name="workflowDefinitions">
        <list>
            <props>
                <prop key="engineId">activiti</prop>
                <prop key="location">alfresco/module/${project.artifactId}/workflows/helloWorld.bpmn</prop>
                <prop key="mimetype">text/xml</prop>
                <prop key="redeploy">false</prop>
            </props>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

In addition, what is the bean id and prop key="loaction" value in this case?

If the above solution is not correct, May I know the correct procedure for deploy the workflow to alfresco 4.2c community?

Answer (score 2):

Did you even look at tutorials? Read the official documentation or even the Wiki Pages, clearly you didn't and hence you're asking the same questions which are answered before.

Take a look at this question [What is the most straight-forward method to deploy a new workflow definition in Alfresco Community 4.0.e?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15320807/what-is-the-most-straight-forward-method-to-deploy-a-new-workflow-definition-in)

Read all the links he mentions, then read this http://ecmarchitect.com/alfresco-developer-series-tutorials/workflow/tutorial/tutorial.html

And then come back with your questions.